# Java - Confused on the line with for loop:

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, indexing, indexoutofboundsexception

```
        int count = 0;
        double [][] x = new double [3][];
        
        x [0] = new double [2];
        x[1] = new double [1];
        x[2] = new double [3];
        for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < x[2].length; j++){  
                x[i][j] = Math.random();
                count +=1;
                System.out.println (i + " " + j);
                
                System.out.println (x[i][j]);
                System.out.println (count);
            }
        }
        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println (x[2][1]);
       System.out.println (count);
    }
}
```

I am confused on the line with second for loop, specifically the output that this line generates once I print out the indexes of i and j. So whenever I have x[i].length, it's returning the indexes for whole array, which I understand but for x[1].length it only returns 00 10 20 indexes, for x[2].length it returns 00 01, and for x[0].length it returns 00 01 10, I am not sure how the program is doing that. Because I thought x[0].length would return 00 01 and x[1].length would return 00, and x[2].length would return 20 21 22

Comment: The second for loop is running until `x[2].length` for every iteration of the first for loop. Your code should throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`, the outer for loop goes from `0 ... 3` and `x` is of size `3` with indexes `0, 1, 2` - so `x[3]` is out of bounds.

Comment: The for loop conditionals should subtract `1` from the array lengths and the inner for loop's conditional should be `j < x[i].length - 1`. Notice I swapped the array indexer of `2` with `i`.

Comment: My first loop goes from index 0 to 2 since it's less than and I don't have x[3], I have x[2], so I am a bit confused